# How do I set the width of the background color equal to the width of the heading tags?

Tags: html, css

When I resize (shrink) the browser, the header elements will move onto the white space. I want them to stay within the blue background color regardless of resizing the browser.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

aside {
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
  background-color: blue;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h3>Home</h3>
    <h3>About</h3>
    <h3>Recent Projects</h3>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `%` as a value. Otherwise, it scales to that percentage.

ie; `grid-template-columns: 15%;` means `15%` of the available window size.

You are best setting static widths as opposed to percentage widths.

You can have a `width` set on your `aside` CSS to override the percentage, example;

```
aside {
    grid-row: 1 / 5;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 160px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your CSS, and I clarified the dimensions. Hopefully this works :)

```
body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

aside {
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

.sidebar h3 {
  width: 130px;
}
```

Comment: had 2 extra spaces before code lines, that's what the edit was for :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `minmax()` and remove the `position:fixed`

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(max-content,15%);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

aside {
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
  background-color: blue;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h3>Home</h3>
    <h3>About</h3>
    <h3>Recent Projects</h3>
  </div>
</aside>
```